# prysm beacon lost sync or re-sync after shanghai upgrade

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, prysm

My node has been down for the last 2 days and seems to be resyncing or now falling behind after Shanghai change, is this normal do I simply wait it out?  I did a pre-upgrade before the change everything was working then just stopped probably after the Shanghai change.  I after I upgraded everything and still same issue.

root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# curl http://localhost:3500/eth/v1/node/syncing | jq
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    96  100    96    0     0  41432      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48000
{
"data": {
"head_slot": "6209535",
"sync_distance": "15444",
"is_syncing": true,
"is_optimistic": false
}
}

root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# curl http://localhost:3500/eth/v1/node/syncing | jq
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    96  100    96    0     0  51391      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 96000
{
"data": {
"head_slot": "6209535",
"sync_distance": "15449",
"is_syncing": true,
"is_optimistic": false
}
}

root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# geth attach --exec eth.syncing --datadir /var/lib/geth
false

#39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 17:33:16 UTC 2023

geth version 1.11.5-stable-a38f4108
validator version Prysm/v4.0.0/191e603e2816e63ca8b1d2615634108e009caceb. Built at: 2023-03-28 15:51:06+00:00
beacon-chain version Prysm/v4.0.2/75338dd83d943ed5e13635cd0578c38a3b2d248b. Built at: 2023-04-13 03:16:53+00:00

root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl --unit=prysmvalidator.service -n 20 --no-pager
Apr 15 01:58:23 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:23" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:29 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:29" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:35 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:35" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:41 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:41" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:47 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:47" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:53 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:53" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:59 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:59" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:05 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:05" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:11 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:11" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:17 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:17" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:23 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:23" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:29 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:29" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:35 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:35" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:41 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:41" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:47 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:47" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:53 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:53" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:59 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:59" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:05 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:05" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:11 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:11" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:17 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:17" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl --unit=prysmbeacon.service -n 20 --no-pager
Apr 15 01:57:13 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:57:13" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=45 inbound=0 outbound=45 prefix=p2p
Apr 15 01:57:16 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:57:16" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:57:16 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:57:16" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 01:57:58 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:57:58" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:57:58 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:57:58" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 01:58:13 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:13" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=44 inbound=0 outbound=44 prefix=p2p
Apr 15 01:58:25 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:25" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:58:25 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:25" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 01:58:38 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:38" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:58:38 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:38" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 01:58:58 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:58" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:58:58 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:58" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 01:59:13 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:13" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=46 inbound=0 outbound=46 prefix=p2p
Apr 15 01:59:46 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:46" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 01:59:46 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:46" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 02:00:00 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:00" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 02:00:00 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:00" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
Apr 15 02:00:13 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:13" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=45 inbound=0 outbound=45 prefix=p2p
Apr 15 02:00:16 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:16" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x8bc7203e123cef451aadcaa541970a5c6c61780c3a9550893daecda7a9bc8166 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=6209582
Apr 15 02:00:16 eth1 beacon-chain[1415]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:16" level=warning msg="Block is not processed" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=initial-sync
root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl --unit=prysmvalidator.service -n 20 --no-pager
Apr 15 01:58:35 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:35" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:41 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:41" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:47 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:47" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:53 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:53" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:58:59 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:58:59" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:05 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:05" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:11 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:11" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:17 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:17" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:23 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:23" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:29 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:29" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:35 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:35" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:41 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:41" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:47 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:47" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:53 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:53" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 01:59:59 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 01:59:59" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:05 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:05" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:11 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:11" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:17 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:17" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:23 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:23" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
Apr 15 02:00:29 eth1 validator[685]: time="2023-04-15 02:00:29" level=info msg="Waiting for beacon node to sync to latest chain head" prefix=validator
root@eth1:/etc/systemd/system# journalctl --unit=geth.service -n 20 --no-pager
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: ########## BAD BLOCK #########
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: Block: 17034870 (0x57f77052f67cdbdb14987b46d3a2d6f001dee0e974cb21da7f59c6dea4ad39c7)
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: Error: missing withdrawalsHash
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: Platform: geth (devel) go1.20.2 amd64 linux
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: VCS: a38f4108-20230321
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: Chain config: &params.ChainConfig{ChainID:1, HomesteadBlock:1150000, DAOForkBlock:1920000, DAOForkSupport:true, EIP150Block:2463000, EIP150Hash:0x2086799aeebeae135c246c65021c82b4e15a2c451340993aacfd2751886514f0, EIP155Block:2675000, EIP158Block:2675000, ByzantiumBlock:4370000, ConstantinopleBlock:7280000, PetersburgBlock:7280000, IstanbulBlock:9069000, MuirGlacierBlock:9200000, BerlinBlock:12244000, LondonBlock:12965000, ArrowGlacierBlock:13773000, GrayGlacierBlock:15050000, MergeNetsplitBlock:, ShanghaiTime:(*uint64)(0xc0001ae190), CancunTime:(*uint64)(nil), PragueTime:(*uint64)(nil), TerminalTotalDifficulty:58750000000000000000000, TerminalTotalDifficultyPassed:true, Ethash:(*params.EthashConfig)(0x2b77940), Clique:(*params.CliqueConfig)(nil)}
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: Receipts:
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: ##############################
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]:
Apr 15 00:37:13 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|00:37:13.394] NewPayloadV1: inserting block failed     error="missing withdrawalsHash"
Apr 15 00:55:55 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|00:55:55.653] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!
Apr 15 01:00:55 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:00:55.683] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!
Apr 15 01:17:45 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:17:45.458] Peer delivering stale transactions       peer=8e115fa3c7cafe2895766f7ba57c7355445ff1d36be78f515cb3fd2333523b3d rejected=44
Apr 15 01:20:55 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:20:55.807] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!
Apr 15 01:23:05 eth1 geth[611]: INFO [04-15|01:23:05.572] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/var/lib/geth/geth/triecache threads=1
Apr 15 01:23:05 eth1 geth[611]: INFO [04-15|01:23:05.575] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
Apr 15 01:23:06 eth1 geth[611]: INFO [04-15|01:23:06.429] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/var/lib/geth/geth/triecache elapsed=856.541ms
Apr 15 01:25:55 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:25:55.839] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!
Apr 15 01:41:20 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:41:20.939] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!
Apr 15 01:46:20 eth1 geth[611]: WARN [04-15|01:46:20.971] Previously seen beacon client is offline. Please ensure it is operational to follow the chain!

Comment: Welcome! But please read around why this will be closed for now. Presumably you have also read https://blog.ethereum.org/2023/03/28/shapella-mainnet-announcement